# MIPS Roman numeral converter

Tags: converters, mips, mips32, roman-numerals

So I am in the beginning stages of planning my Roman numeral converter (Roman numerals to integers) in MIPS. I am stuck on how to convert the numbers where there's a number less than the next number (i.e. `IV` [`4`]). I was thinking about doing the below but it still doesn't solve my problem.

put this somewhere in the data section:

```
all_numerals: .asciiz "IVXLCDMivxlcdm"
all_values:   .byte 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000
```

I would then read the character and compare it to its index in `all_values` and add that to a register and repeat.

Does anyone know an efficient way to do this? As it stands I am going to do a loop that would compare the last character (`I` [`1`]) to the next character (`V` [`5`]) and if it is less subtract the character from the most recent (`5 - 1`), but I think this would be inefficient. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: See http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Roman_numerals/Decode#C

Comment: Michael, is there a way to easily convert C/C++/Java to MIPS? I am coming from only a Java background so I am not as familiar. The code that you linked is exactly what I need for my mips program.

Comment: You could use a C cross compiler that runs on an x86 host and targets MIPS devices (use a search engine, because asking people to find tools for you is off-topic for StackOverflow). The other way would be to learn the MIPS instruction set. Assuming that you're able to understand how the original C/C++/Java code works you then implement the same thing in MIPS assembly. Don't expect to be done in 15 minutes if you're just starting out; you'll have to spend some time on it.